# BindValue does not accept false value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a text data type in a database that would like to enter true or false values. If I do using Mysqli or PDO with BindParam works correctly it adds 1 or 0 but when I try to use BindValue it only works true. False value is exchanged for an empty space.

[image: empty values]

```
try{
 $conn =  new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name_db", "root", "");
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO upload_meta (video_id, upload_key, upload_value) VALUES (:video_id,:upload_key,:upload_value)"; 
 $temp = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $temp->bindValue(':video_id', 11111111);
 $temp->bindValue(':upload_key', 'exodo');
 $temp->bindValue(':upload_value', false);

$temp->execute();   

}catch(PDOException $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();


}
```

This field will receive values of various types needing to be text.

```
CREATE TABLE `upload_meta` (
  `meta_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `upload_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `upload_value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `video_id` (`video_id`),
  KEY `index_upload_key` (`upload_key`(191)),
  CONSTRAINT `upload_meta_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `video` (`id_video`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Details on the schema, especially the type of the `upload_value` column would be useful...

Comment: `false` casts to an empty string. Why not explicitly use 1 or 0?

Comment: Using 0 the same problem occurs and it inserts an empty space.

Comment: sorry but  I don't understand the question. ...why you have a text type for store boolean value? and if works bindParam why you don't use?

Comment: 1 ° This field "meta_value" will not only store boolean, it will be variable the types of data that it will store.

2 ° I do not use bindParam because I want to understand why BindValue is not working as expected. I suppose there must be some explanation and solution to this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to the documentation**

The answer is in the documentation for [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

And [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

> call PDOStatement::bindParam() to bind PHP variables to the parameter markers: bound variables pass their value as input and receive the output value, if any, of their associated parameter markers

**Your case**

Your database structure expects `upload_value` as varchar which is basically text/string. When you use `bindParam` it is working because it is passing the value of true or false i.e., 1 or 0

But when you use `bindValue` the reference is passed and then evaluated at the time of execution, and hence true is getting converted into 1 (string/text), but false is evaluated to "empty" string.

**Solution**

Either use `bindParam` or if you want to use `bindValue` you should update your database structure to accept boolean values for `upload_value` instead of varchar

A 5 min guide: https://w3guy.com/php-pdostatement-bindparam-bindvalue/

Comment: Good answer after much research I was able to use adding PDO :: NULL_NATURAL in bindValue I do not know if it is the correct way, if it can generate some error in the future, but it worked. Maybe you should add this option to your answer.

Comment: That worked, great! But you should consider updating your data type in the database i.e., replace varchar with boolean